# How to calculate TimeDifference using SQL in SQL Server 2005 equivalent to Excel formula?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
StartTime   EndTime  TimeDifference
6:36:56     6:36:56  00:31 :52
7:08:48     7:26:18  00:00 :23
7:26:41     8:08:26  00:00 :09
08:35.0     16:54.0  00:09 :42
26:36.0     59:34.0  00:00 :09
59:43.0     19:13.0  #VALUE!
```

This calculation is performed in Excel using formula F(x) =TEXT(A3 - B2, "hh:mm:ss") but how can I accomplish this using SQL in SQL Server 2005? 
Remember, headers are in row # 1whereas actual time begins in row#2,#3, etc. Therefore, 7:08:48 - 6:36:56 = 00:31:52 respectively is correct and this is how I want to calculate. Caution: I don't want to calculate like this (7:26:18 - 7:08:48   = 00:17:30) it is simple and doesn't align with my business need and I know it.

Comment: Please be gentle, polite and professional. At this juncture you are like me "frustrated" and can't provide the algorithm so you are writing that you are not a code service. I am struggling to come up with an algorithm. Can anyone come up with an SQL based algorithm looking at the above example?  How do I populate TimeDifference calculated column. It is easy in Excel not in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try for exemple

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'7:08:48','7:26:18'),'2011-01-01 00:00:00.000'),114)
```

Comment: I already know this and this is not what I am looking for. My current SQL code generates what I Have shown above except that TimeDifference column has value 0:00:00 since it is not calculated. What I need to know how do I populate calculated column TimeDifference using SQL code. I need algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATEDIFF function to get the difference for a time part between two DateTime values (see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp)

For example the following SQL will give you Hours, Minutes and Seconds between two DateTimes

```
DECLARE @DT1 DATETIME

SET @DT1= '2016-04-18'
DECLARE @DT2 DATETIME 
SET @DT2 = GETDATE()

SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, @DT1, @DT2) AS [Hours],
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @DT1, @DT2) - (DATEDIFF(HOUR, @DT1, @DT2) * 60) AS [Minutes],
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, @DT1, @DT2) - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @DT1, @DT2) * 60) AS [Seconds]

Hours   Minutes Seconds
16      31      35
```

What you are trying to do however is to find the difference between DateTimes on different rows and so you need to join the table on to itself using an OUTER APPLY as follows (if you have an incrementing ID column then a LEFT JOIN on tb1a.id = tb1b.id + 1 will perform better) :

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (Date1 DATETIME, Date2 DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES('2016-04-18 10:01', '2016-04-18 10:02')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES( '2016-04-18 10:06','2016-04-18 10:09')

SELECT t1a.Date1, t1a.Date2 , t1b.Date1, t1b.Date2 
FROM @Table1 t1a
OUTER APPLY 
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 Date1, Date2 FROM @Table1 t1b WHERE Date1 > t1a.Date1 ORDER BY Date1
    ) t1b
```

Which gives you:

```
Date1                  Date2                 NextDate1              NextDate2
2016-04-18 10:01:00    2016-04-18 10:02:00   2016-04-18 10:06:00    2016-04-18 10:09:00
2016-04-18 10:06:00    2016-04-18 10:09:00   NULL                   NULL
```

Then all you need to do is use DATEDIFF as above to produce you Time Difference

Comment: Please allow me to explain- My current SQL code generates what I Have shown above except that TimeDifference column has value 0:00:00 since it is not calculated. What I need to know how do I populate calculated column TimeDifference?

Comment: Use the DATEDIFF function or subtract the two dates and take the right part as the time: SELECT CAST('2016-01-10 15:00:15' AS DATETIME) - CAST('2016-01-10 14:35:15' AS DATETIME)

Comment: It is not about direct subtraction. How do I tell me algorithm to look at StartTime Row#2, Value (7:08:48 ) - EndTime Row#1, Value ( 6:36:56) and StartTime Row#3, Value (7:26:41 ) - EndTime, Row #2, Value(7:26:18) and so on to get the desired output. It means in the StartTime column it is always ONE row ahead of the EndTime column which is a tricky part. I can perform ROW to ROW direct subtraction using DateDiff () without any issue. I hope it helps.

Comment: If you look at the last half of my answer this shows how to get the next rows values in the current rows output.

Comment: OK. Let me play with it and I will get back to you. I guess I overlooked your hard work.